# How to fix App Store connect demo video error?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I’m trying to upload an speedometer app to apple App Store. But I get this error message from apple:

Does your app interact with hardware, and if so please provide a link to a demo video that demonstrates the current version of your app in use on a physical iOS device, which shows the initial pairing process and entire app workflow with the designated hardware.

I have sent them an video of the whole app but don’t accept it. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: It sounds like you need to answer their question "our app does. It interact with hardware"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video, make sure you demonstrate the pairing of the  "physical iOS device" and other hardware(BLE device?).
I think there is no other way to make your app approved.

Comment: Okay. But what do you mean with pairing?

Comment: According by AppleStore's reply, your App is used with some smart device, like Bluetooth watch etc. before using the app , you need to get  the device pairing (Bluetooth pairing) first.  So you have to record a video to show that how the App work with the smart device.

Comment: Ok. I need to check it out because it just uses the device location, no other hardware.

Answer (score 1):

With another phone take a video of your iPhone using the app physically.

For example: while walking record yourself holding the phone and the speedometer changing.

Also, tell Apple that your app does not interact with external hardware.